# Disabling first item to dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of dropdowns and I would like to disable the first item, before I was trying to apply onClick, but won't work so well and now I am trying to disable using this way:

```
 $("select option:first-child").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

But won't work too, some idea?

Thank you

Comment: your answer is correct, but use :first instead of :first-child i think

Comment: @omikes is correct, 
use $("select option:first").attr("disabled", "disabled");

Answer (score 6):

Simply do this

```
$("select option:first").attr("disabled", "true");
```

Comment: Please explain more. Why does this help? What is the difference to the older answer by Diwakar Singh? What is the advantage compared to that answer?

Comment: There isn't any advantage, it simply gives to the point answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is ok just a change

Make Disable true like below:

```
$("select option:first-child").attr("disabled", "true");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("select option[value='']:selected").attr('disabled',"disabled"); });
```

My solution. After load all dropdowns, I just need to set disabled the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jQuery's hide right on page ready; after the top option for the dropdown is set as the title, remove it from the list.

```js
$('option[value=""]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="clientName" id="clientName"> 
    <option name="" value="">Client Name</option>
    <option name="Jennifer Black" value="0">Jennifer Black</option>
    <option name="Henry Johnson" value="1">Henry Johnson</option>
    <option name="Jack Hunnington" value="2">Jack Hunnington</option>
    <option name="Mary Green" value="3">Mary Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. I want to disable it and you are removing it.